# Connecting to a database setting a cookie, using a function in php

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I want to be able to connect to my database and have my function search the database for the logged in user and set a cookie, using the users username.

I want to do this using PHP.

I want to do this so that I can call the username whenever I want to display it.

I am very new at php so please bear with me.

Even if there is a link to a post about this, that would be helpful

Edit (This is what I tried so far):

```
function storeUsername{

$sql = "SELECT username, id FROM users WHERE email = '".escape($email)."' AND active = 1";


    $result = query($sql);

      if(row_count($result) == 1) {

          $row = fetch_array($result);

          $username = $row['username'];


            {

                setcookie('username', $username, time() + 500000);

            }


            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;



            return true;

        } else {


            return false;
        }









        return true;

    } else {


        return false;



    }
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? Here at Stack Overflow you need to give an example of your attempt so far.

Comment: @Jamesking56 I have editted it with the function I have tried already. I'm unfortunately terrible at php so it might look really dumb